# How do I correctly typeset metastable radionuclide symbols?

Tags: elements, notation, radioactivity

Does anyone know if there is an officially sanctioned way to typeset symbols like technetium-99m (<sup>99</sup>Tc<sup>m</sup> or <sup>99m</sup>Tc)? I have seen both, although in more recent publications, I think, the latter predominates.

For my part, it looks somewhat wrong to place the symbol for metastable in the position you'd normally expect the charge. How would you write the ion, <sup>99</sup>Tc<sup>m+</sup>? That looks quite clumsy.

So does anyone know if there's some IUPAC (or similarly authoritative) guidance on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the international standard ISO 80000 *Quantities and units* – Part 9: *Physical chemistry and molecular physics*, Amendment 1, a metastable nuclide is indicated by adding the letter m (in roman type) to the mass number of the nuclide, as in the following examples:

$$\mathrm{^{133m}Xe}$$
$$\mathrm{^{99m}Tc^+}$$

Comment: I'm quite confused since BS ISO 80000-9:2009 (Annex B, p. 34) suggests otherwise: "State of nuclear excitation: $\ce{^110Ag^*}$ or $\ce{^110Ag^\mathrm{m}}$". Are you citing a more recent ISO, maybe?

Comment: @andselisk Yes indeed. The first edition of ISO 80000-9 (2009-04-01) had in Annex B: “$\ce{^110Ag^*}$ or $\ce{^110Ag^\mathrm{m}}$”. This mistake was corrected in Amendment 1 (2011-06-01).

Answer (score 3):

According to *IUPAP recommendations (Symbols, Units, Nomenclature and Fundamental Constants in Physics), part 2 SYMBOLS FOR ELEMENTS, PARTICLES, STATES AND TRANSITIONS, 2.1 Chemical elements*, both placements are valid [1, p. 9]:

> The right superscript position should be used, if required, to indicate a state of ionization (*e.g.*, $\ce{Ca^2+}$, $\ce{PO4^3-}$) or an excited *atomic* state (e.g., $\ce{He^∗}$). A metastable *nuclear* state, however, often is
> treated as a distinct nuclide: *e.g.*, either $\ce{^118Ag^\mathrm{m}}$ or $\ce{^\mathrm{118m}Ag}$.

---

On the other hand, *AIP Style Guide in Part III. General style, A. GRAMMAR AND PUNCTUATION, 12. Symbols for nuclides* suggests that roman "m" is placed as superscript on the right [2, p. 16]:

> Journals of AIP and its Member Societies follow the recommendations of the Symbols, Units, and Nomencla­ture (S.U.N.) Commission of the International Union of Pure and Applied Physics on the symbols to be used for nuclides and their states. [...]
>
> A posterior superscript can indicate either a state of ioni­zation:
> $$\ce{Ca^2+}$$
> or an excited state:
> $$\ce{^110Ag^\mathrm{m}},~\ce{^14N^*}$$

#### References

1. [Cohen, R. E.; Giacomo, P. IUPAP “Red Book” Symbols, Units, Nomenclature and Fundamental Constants in Physics (2010 Reprint); IUPAP recommendations; Commission C2 – Sunamco, 1987.](http://iupap.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/A4.pdf)
2. AIP Style Manual, 4th ed.; American Institute of Physics, AIP Publication Board, Eds.; American Institute of Physics: New York, N.Y., 1990. ISBN 978-0-88318-642-8.