# Nuclear equations for the decay of radon-222 to lead-206

Tags: radioactivity, nuclear-chemistry

I have to answer this on my worksheet. I understand nuclear chemistry equations a bit, as well as the process of alpha decay and somewhat about what happens when an atom changes its number of protons and neutrons, I understand the gamma symbol and the m symbol meaning the element is high-energy state but this has me stumped. It's an 8 step question. It reads:

> The inhalation of radon-222 and its decay to form other isotopes poses a health hazard.
>   Write balanced nuclear equations for the decay of radon-222 to lead-206 in eight steps.
>   Show step 1 below, and show steps 2-8 are on the next page.
>
> **a**. Step 1: radon-222 decays by alpha emission.
>
> **b**. Step 2: the daughter product in part a decays by alpha emission and is in a high energy state.
>
> **c**. Step 3: the high energy daughter product in part **b** decays by beta and gamma emissions and is in a high energy state.
>
> **d**. Step 4: the daughter product in part **c** decays by beta and gamma emissions and is in a high energy state.
>
> **e**. Step 5: the high energy daughter product in part **d** decays by beta emission.
>
> **f**. Step 6: the daughter product in part **e** decays by alpha emission and is in a high energy state.
>
> **g**. Step 7: the high energy daughter product in part **f** decays by beta and gamma emissions and is in a high energy state.
>
> **h**. Step 8: the high energy daughter product in part **g** decays by alpha and gamma emissions.

Comment: Did you forget to type out part a) of the question? According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Decay_chain(4n%2B2,_Uranium_series).svg, it should be an alpha decay.

Comment: My bad. Part 1 a. Step 1: Radon-222 decays by alpha emission. (Radon has the element symbol Rn.) yes it is an alpha decay. I just dont understand how to explain all this through equation as this is literally my first problem like this ever.

Comment: Im asusming it starts as 222m/86 Rn----->0/-1 B+(gamma symbol)

Comment: You seem to be missing the essential difference between alpha and beta.

Comment: Believe it or not, that last comment helped A LOT. Thanks

Comment: So what is your first step equation now?

Comment: basically 222/86 Rn--->4/2alpha+218/84Po. then for B. I got 218/84 Po--->4/2alpha+214/82Pb. Then for c, I got  214Pb--->0/-1Beta+214/83 Bi+0/0y. For d, I got 214/83 Bi+0/0y--->0/-1Beta+214/84Po+0/0y.

Comment: e. 214/84 Po+0/0y--->0/-1Beta+214/85 At  . F. 214/85 At+0/0y--->4/2 alpha+210/83Pb. G. 210/83 Bi--->4/2 Alpha+206/81 Hg+0/0y. H. 206/81Hg+0/0y--->4/2 Alpha+202/79....thats where Im lost because this doesnt seem to add up to 206 lead

Answer (score 3):

In any nuclear reactions the sum of the [mass numbers $A_i$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_number) (the sum of the indices on the top left) of the reagents and products is always the same. The same applies to [nuclear charges $Z_i$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_number) (indices in the lower left, which are often not indicated). Also, keep in mind the [notation for metastable state](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/50305/how-do-i-correctly-typeset-metastable-radionuclide-symbols):

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{^{222}_{86}Rn &→ ^{218}_{84}Po + ^{4}_{2}He}\tag{a} \\
\ce{^{218}_{84}Po &→ ^{214\mathrm{m}}_{82}Pb + ^{4}_{2}He}\tag{b} \\
\ce{^{214\mathrm{m}}_{82}Pb &→ ^{214\mathrm{m}}_{83}Bi + ^{0}_{-1}e + γ}\tag{c} \\
\ce{^{214\mathrm{m}}_{83}Bi &→ ^{214\mathrm{m}}_{84}Po + ^{0}_{-1}e + γ}\tag{d} \\
\ce{^{214\mathrm{m}}_{84}Po &→ ^{214}_{85}At + ^{0}_{-1}e}\tag{e} \\
\ce{^{214}_{85}At &→ ^{210\mathrm{m}}_{83}Bi + ^{4}_{2}He}\tag{f} \\
\ce{^{210\mathrm{m}}_{83}Bi &→ ^{210\mathrm{m}}_{84}Po + ^{0}_{-1}e + γ}\tag{g} \\
\ce{^{210\mathrm{m}}_{84}Po &→ ^{206}_{82}Pb + ^{4}_{2}He + γ}\tag{h} \\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: "High energy state" indicates that the nucleus will first decay with emission of a gamma ray, then a particle emission. $$\ce{^{210m}_{84}Po -> ^{210}_{84}Po + \gamma -> ^{206}_82Pb + ^4_2He }$$

Comment: @MaxW That's right, but OP was asked to right down the equations for each "*step*", and those didn't differentiate gamma emission from the decay acts, unfortunately. Thanks for your comment though!

Comment: I understand this is a site where there are some people who are very serious about Chemistry. TBH this is my fourth week of this ever. I am also on Calculus one rn and I'm definitely struggling. I plan to explore as much chemistry as I can take. Im a veteran and a total meat head lol. It WILL take some getting used to. However, You guys are pretty awesome. I hope to exceed and study more sciences in the future and I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: @andselisk: Step (h) in your answer should be: $\ce{^{210\mathrm{m}}_{84}Po -> ^{206}_{82}Pb + ^{4}_{2}He + \gamma}$ (not $\ce{^{210\mathrm{m}}_{84}Po -> ^{206}_{82}Po + ^{4}_{2}He + \gamma}$ as stated). :-)

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne Thank you very much, fixed. I knew I would miss something as being lazy I iteratively copy-pasted equations:)